# Burninate [stop]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, tag-block-request

Questions tagged [stop](/questions/tagged/stop) look unrelated amongst each other as the tag may refer to:

- **a video/music player stopping**

  - [MPMoviePlayerController Crashing on iOS 7 when stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977490/mpmovieplayercontroller-crashing-on-ios-7-when-stopped)
  - [Android MediaPlayer stops playing after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566450/android-mediaplayer-stops-playing-after-some-time)
- **a program/application/thread stopping**

  - [My app still runs after it stops. How can I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328698/my-app-still-runs-after-it-stops-how-can-i-stop-it)
  - [Is it safe to use `System.exit()` to stop a java application which has an embed Jetty server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938929/is-it-safe-to-use-system-exit-to-stop-a-java-application-which-has-an-embed)
  - [How a thread should close itself in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491588/how-a-thread-should-close-itself-in-java)
- **prevent something/someone from doing something**

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513185/stop-third-party-application-previously-started-by-intent
  - [How to STOP redirecting my website to mobile.mywebsite.com in smartphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285238/how-to-stop-redirecting-my-website-to-mobile-mywebsite-com-in-smartphones)
- **literally anything that can be stopped**

  - [Can't stop requestAnimationFrame (Javascript/html5: canvas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449219/cant-stop-requestanimationframe-javascript-html5-canvas)
  - [How to stop scrolling ontouchscreen in custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413513/how-to-stop-scrolling-ontouchscreen-in-custom-view)

Also, looking at the extremely generic tag description

> The act of causing execution to end.

[stop](/questions/tagged/stop) doesn't look like a well-defined category, so I believe it's not a good fit for a tag.

Can we please burninate (and possibly blacklist) this tag and STOP people from using it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this also means [stop][hammertime] cannot be done. :-(

Comment: ***Hammertime!!!*** ...oh, Jamal already used that word.

Comment: thanks for making it more clear :) BURNINATE!

Comment: @AsshO.Le thanks for helping me in the process

Comment: @Jamal, we can also no longer [stop][collaborate][listen] if this goes through.

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: @Jamal Blacklisting is for tags that are repeatedly recreated, in order to **stop** this from happening (and it's a pretty extreme thing - it can only be done by the dev team). Unless there is evidence of this, a simple burnination should be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, we haven't had success in getting a tag blacklisted in literally years.  Once `stop` has been nuked, I'll stick it on the list of the **102** tags I keep dead every day.